# Current display mode

Tags: graphics, display, kms, drm

Under the sysfs drm module I can obtain all available modes for a particular connector at /sys/class/drm/card0-*/modes. Is it possible or even logical to request the current state the card is in? All documentation I've read is oriented towards setting the mode rather than getting it.<sup>[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_setting)][[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager)]</sup>

Comment: `xrandr` will give a list of available modes and the current one. You can add `--verbose` option for more detailed output. BTW, I'm voting to reopen this question.

Comment: @jimmij It doesn't appear to be display server agnostic nor does it help understanding the drm unless it's the responsibility of the drm master to maintain the current state, if anybody knows.